# css nth-child(1) chose the second element, why?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What I want: To understand nth-child(n). My understanding is that the nth-
child(1) will choose every first element. So apple, fruit, banana should be chosen to display red.

What actually shows: But tomato and mango were also chosen and displayed red.

Code:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>tomato</li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">fruit</a>
        <a href="#">juice</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <span>
        <a href="#">banana</a>
        <em>mango</em>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Pseudo selectors work slightly differently. They need an element they need to apply the property against. Try `a:nth-child(1)`

Comment: By not specifying an element in front of nth-child, it's applied to *all* elements. So the `<ul>` is the first child in the DOM, the `<span>` is the first child of the `<div>` etc.

Comment: If the whole ul should be chosen, then why "juice" is excluded?

Comment: @paige because the `a` tag specifies black, which will override the inherited value from ul, the first `a` matches both rules, both have the same specificity, so the rules are applied in the order they appear in the code.

Comment: @karthikr No, pseudo-classes (there is no such term as "pseudo-selector") do **not** need an element (although using them by themselves won't usually be that useful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `:nth-child(1)` also includes `html:nth-child(1)`, which means all text will be red. Also note that `ul` is the first child of `body`. (`html` and `body` elements are added when you run the snippet.)

The reason almost all text is red is somewhat complicated:

- apple: red because it is text in the first `li` element of the `ul`
- tomato: red because it inherits the color of `ul`, which is the first element in `body`
- fruit: red because it is the text of the first `a` in an `li` element (styling of `:nth-child(1)` wins)
- juice: black because it is the text of an `a` element that is not the first child of another element (styling of `a` is used)
- banana: red because it is the text of the first child of a `span` element
- mango: red because `em` inherits the text color of its parent (`span`) which is the first child of a `div`, so the styling of `:nth-child(1)` is applied

Also note that any text in the `div` will be red, because the `div` inherits the color from `html` (which is a first child). You may want to specify an explicit text color for `html` which can be used instead.

Comment: OK I took another look at selectors-4, and it seems to suggest that :nth-child() has been changed from css3-selectors and will now match the root element. Problem is that the DOM spec from which it takes its definitions insists that elements must have a parent for the purposes of matching these pseudos. I'll see if I can clear things up with the CSSWG. In the meantime, Chrome and Firefox do match the root element, while IE, Edge and Safari don't.

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Arjan answer is perfect. In addition to that I have changed your code for your better understanding.

```
    <ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>tomato</li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">fruit</a>
        <a href="#">juice</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <span>
        <a href="#">banana</a>
        <em>mango</em>
    </span>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/PrakashS/mcz1ykm9/)

and this link will help you to understand better to know more about nth-child in css http://nthmaster.com/